# How to get values from two columns in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table Students which has student_id (Pk) and two columns class_id and class_id2 as a student can be registered in two classes 
i would like to use Code-igniter to get the values of both columns and i tried arrays but it doesn't seem to work as it gets all students

```
<?php 
   $students   =   $this->db->get_where('student' , array('class_id'=>$class_id) )->result_array();
      foreach($students as $row):?>
           <tr class="gradeA">
                <td><?php echo $row['roll'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
<?php
```

when i change the value to class_id2 it gets the values from that column but i don't know if there is a way i can get both?

Comment: you want get data  by where clause that contains two class_1 and class_2 condition. am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
$this->db->or_where("class_id",$class_id);
$this->db->or_where("class_id2",$class_id);
$students   =   $this->db->get('student')->result_array();
```

Comment: Perfect couldn't have done it better, your the best mate

Comment: One more sugession from my side, try avoiding wtriting queries in views.

Comment: writing queries in views, sorry but i didn't quite get that term 'views'

Comment: Not sure what the file suffix/extension is for codeigniter, but in Zend (for example) a "view" is a .phtml file where values are expanded and put on the screen so users can "view" the result of function calls, and what-not.  In an MVC solution, you usually create functions to do queries inside a "model" and then call to the function within a controller. The view file is a sort-of output template where the results of the function call are displayed to Users.

Comment: You have written the query in view file rite??

Comment: no i don't think i  use a view file i guess, i'm just using textwrangler and checking the results on my local host, i guess it is a long process.